# How to convert Oracle to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, oracle, if-statement, iif, case-statement

I have the following query that I wanted to convert to in SQL Server but not sure how I should go about this. Should I use a CASE statement because I don't see any true/false conditions in this statement. How should I go about this? Thanks!

ORACLE Query:

```
IIF(CD_ID = '999999',TO_CHAR(CL_ID)  || TO_CHAR(CD_SEQ_NO)  ||  '999.99',TO_CHAR(CL_ID)  || TO_CHAR(CD_SEQ_NO)  ||  TO_CHAR(CD_ID))
```

Comment: Oracle supports `IIF`?

Comment: That is definitely **not** a valid Oracle query. There is no `iif` in Oracle

Answer (score 0):

From `SQL SERVER 2012+` we can use `CONCAT` function.

```
SELECT IIF(CD_ID = '999999',CONCAT(CD_SEQ_NO, '999.99'),CONCAT(CL_ID,CD_SEQ_NO,CD_ID))
FROM YOURTABLE
```

`Concat` function not only concatenate the strings but also does *implicit conversion* when required

Anything less then `SQL SERVER 2012` use `CASE` statements with *explicit conversions* to `varchar`

```
SELECT CASE 
         WHEN cd_id = '999999' THEN Cast(cd_seq_no AS VARCHAR(50)) + '999.99' 
         ELSE Cast(cl_id AS VARCHAR(50))+Cast(cd_seq_no AS VARCHAR(50))+Cast(cd_id AS VARCHAR(50))
       END 
FROM   yourtable
```